# Pandas compares scores in row for baseball games

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [402, 402, 402, 402, 403, 403, 404, 404],
                   'Team' : ['SFO', 'ARI', 'CUB', 'STL', 'NYY', 'SEA', 'OAK', 'LAA'],
                   'Final' :[4, 6, 2, 5, 7, 2, 1, 2]})

df_expected =  pd.DataFrame({'Date': [402, 402, 402, 402, 403, 403, 404, 404],
                       'Team' : ['SFO', 'ARI', 'CUB', 'STL', 'NYY', 'SEA', 'OAK', 'LAA'],
                       'Final' :[4, 6, 2, 5, 7, 2, 1, 2], 
                       'Win_Loss': [0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1],
                       'Run_diff': [-2,2,-3,3,5,-5,-1,1]})
```

I am trying to create two columns: Run_diff for the run differential and a binary win/loss column.

Best I have been able to do so far:

Sets up odd even column to try and group games for analysis

```
df['Test'] = 1
for i, j in enumerate(df['Final']):
    if (i % 2) == 0: 
        df['Test'][i] = 'Even'
    else: 
        df['Test'][i] = 'Odd'
```

Attempt to get scores in a row for easier plus/minus

```
df['Shift'] = df['Final'].shift(fill_value = 0)
```

Attempting to work with two created columns above

```
conditions = [(df['Test'] == 'Odd'),
             (df['Test'] == 'Even')]

values = [df['Final'] - df['Shift'], 0]

df['Run_diff'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

This works ok for any Odd columns, which is my attempt to group the rows as games. But I can't figure out how to get the Even columns to work.

You don't have to use my code, since it is not the most elegant. I am sure of that. I am more than willing to try and apply new/better techniques for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there expected output?

Comment: Done. Hopefully, it clarifies my question for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-index by odd and even rows.

Calculate run_diff and win_loss for both teams in a single row.

Then return your data to its initial order by stacking and re-indexing.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [402, 402, 402, 402, 403, 403, 404, 404],
                   'Team': ['SFO', 'ARI', 'CUB', 'STL', 'NYY', 'SEA', 'OAK', 'LAA'],
                   'Final': [4, 6, 2, 5, 7, 2, 1, 2]})

# Re Index Based on Odd And Even Rows
new_df = df.set_index([df.index // 2, df.index % 2]).unstack()

# Calculate Run Diff in Both Directions
new_df['Run_Diff', 0] = new_df['Final', 0] - new_df['Final', 1]
new_df['Run_Diff', 1] = new_df['Final', 1] - new_df['Final', 0]
# Calculate Win Loss in Both Directions
new_df['Win_Loss', 0] = (new_df['Run_Diff', 0] > 0).astype(int)
new_df['Win_Loss', 1] = (new_df['Run_Diff', 1] > 0).astype(int)

# Remove Multi Index, Change Column Order
new_df = (
    new_df.stack(1)
        .reset_index(drop=True)[['Date', 'Team', 'Final', 'Win_Loss', 'Run_Diff']]
)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   Date Team  Final  Win_Loss  Run_Diff
0   402  SFO      4         0        -2
1   402  ARI      6         1         2
2   402  CUB      2         0        -3
3   402  STL      5         1         3
4   403  NYY      7         1         5
5   403  SEA      2         0        -5
6   404  OAK      1         0        -1
7   404  LAA      2         1         1
```

Comment: Thanks, Henry. This really helps and it will give me help studying my data manipulation weaknesses. Mainly, altering indexing and then understanding how to work with a multi-index dataset. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd chose different approach. Looking at your data, I'd first transform your dataframe:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": df["Date"].iloc[::2].values,
        "Team1": df["Team"].iloc[::2].values,
        "Team2": df["Team"].iloc[1::2].values,
        "Final1": df["Final"].iloc[::2].values,
        "Final2": df["Final"].iloc[1::2].values,
    }
)
```

This creates this `new_df`:

```
   Date Team1 Team2  Final1  Final2
0   402   SFO   ARI       4       6
1   402   CUB   STL       2       5
2   403   NYY   SEA       7       2
3   404   OAK   LAA       1       2
```

Then it's easy:

```
new_df["run_diff"] = new_df["Final1"] - new_df["Final2"]
new_df["win_loss"] = (new_df["run_diff"] < 0).astype(int)
print(new_df)
```

Prints:

```
   Date Team1 Team2  Final1  Final2  run_diff  win_loss
0   402   SFO   ARI       4       6        -2         1
1   402   CUB   STL       2       5        -3         1
2   403   NYY   SEA       7       2         5         0
3   404   OAK   LAA       1       2        -1         1
```

Comment: Sorry, I just realized this doesn't work. It doesn't really keep the data in tidy data format. This will make it hard to perform statistical analysis because the information won't be easily attributed to the single team in that row. I am sure I could do it, but I think the analysis will be tough for me. Maybe a more experienced data analyst wouldn't have a problem, but I think it will make the analysis more difficult in this format

Comment: I eventually want to see if I can predict a team's final record and final run differential total at different dates (run it after 30 games, 60 games, ect..) in the baseball season.

Comment: @chasedcribbet If you want back teams in one column, look at `pd.melt` etc. For example `pd.melt(df, id_vars=["Team1"], value_vars=["Final1", "Final2"])` ...

Comment: I was thinking of using melt. Don't have a lot of experience with it, but it would be a great opportunity for me to practice. On another note, I see your answers a lot on here, especially for web scraping questions. I wanted to let you know I really appreciate your contributions. If you ever get  into the tutoring webscraping and API work to help people like me get better at getting our date, let me know. I will be first in line.